# In vscode notebook extension; how do you convert between NotebookCell and NotebookCellData

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating a vscode notebook extension using the [notebook API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api)?

Is there a way to convert between the interface [NotebookCell](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#NotebookCell) and the concrete class [NotebookCellData](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#NotebookCellData).

Some methods return instances of the NotebookCell interface. Notably if I get the cells in the active editor

```
const editor = vscode.window.activeNotebookEditor;
let cells = editor?.notebook.getCells(new vscode.NotebookRange(0, editor?.notebook.cellCount))
```

`cells` is of type `NotebookCell[]`.

However the serializer uses `vscode.NotebookData` which contains a `NotebookCellData[]`.

This leaves me wondering how I can get a consistent representation of the data that I can work with. Concretely, I'd like to write a method `cellsToProto` that converts the notebook into a proto representation. There are two places I'd like to do this conversion

1. In response to various events in the editor (protos are created to send requests to a backend)
2. In the serializer to serialize the notebook as a proto

For the former it seems like the function signature would be

```
function cellsToProto(cells : NotebookCell[]): DocProto
```

But for the serializer it seems like we'd want

```
function cellsToProto(cells : NotebookCellData[]): DocProto
```

I'm looking for a good way to resuse the code for converting the cells to a proto. Is there a routine that will convert a `NotebookCellData` into some class that implements `NotebookCell` or do I have to implement my own conversion?